# How can I create a search bar that will search my website pages?

Tags: html, css, linux

I am creating a website and wish to make my search bar search my website pages. I have already created a search bar place holder shown below but would appreciate advice or guidance to make this search bar search my website pages only and not just google. If you need more details please let me know and I will be happy to provide them.

```
<div class="search-head">
        <form class="search-bar" action="">
            <input class="search-barinpt" type="text" placeholder="Search Here"/> 
            <button type="submit"><img class="search-img" src="/images-for-website/search-icon.png"></button>             
      </form>
     </div>
```

So far I have created a search bar, formatted the search bar, and implemented it to all of my website pages. But cannot figure out how to make it search within my website pages.

Comment: If you are using php or asp, you need to create a script that will use keywords from your search bar and find something in your database

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment, I am currently using HTML, CSS, and php. My website is quite large 22-23 pages. Do you have any recommendations about how to add all of this information into the database? Sorry for this question if it is a "dumb question". I've created a website form in the past but have never created a working search bar so I am quite lost on what to do or how to add such an abundance of information into a database. Any references you could provide would be amazing.

Comment: You need to create database with for exemple a "posts" table inside, check on internet, you'll find so many tutorial about it

Comment: Thank you, I have been researching all day and their is limited information on how to index my site or create a database from my website.

Comment: https://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-your-own-search-engine-using-php-jquery-and-mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches: you either install and manage your own search engine, or you use a managed one.

- Self-hosted search engines such as [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/), [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/) and [Meilisearch](https://www.meilisearch.com/).
- Managed search services such as [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/), [Google Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/about/) and [Lixia Search](https://www.lixiasearch.com/).